# PHP Regex - only allow certain numbers

Tags: php, regex

```
$output = preg_replace( '/[^0-9]/', '', $string );
```

How can I change the above line to only accept `11 digit` long numbers that must start with either `01, 02, 03, 05, 07 or 08, but NOT 04, 06, 09`

Comment: _start with either..._ - you mean the last two characters (digits)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use following pattern:

```
 /^0[123578]{1}[0-9]{9}$/
```

Comment: you'd also need a `^` at the start as the string must start with a zero - `/^0...`

Comment: Thanks for the input. Also added end of string ( $)

Comment: @PhilipG This will wrong regex. It accepts x, y, / etc at second character. For example `0x`, `00`, `0Z`, `0#`... and so on

Answer (score 2):

Try this one:

```
$output = preg_replace( '/^0[1-3578]\d{9}/', '', $string );
```

`\d{9}` means 9 digits as you have already 2 digits back.

Comment: how do I implement this as an if statement. I.e if valid or if not

Comment: if you want to use if then use `preg_match` `if(preg_match("/^0[1-3578]\d{9}/", $string)){`

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
/^0[123578][0-9]{9}$/
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
^0[1-3578]\d{9}$
```

[image: Regular expression visualization]

`0`-Zero `[^469]`-Number except 469 `\d`-Any Number

Comment: This will wrong regex. It accepts `x`, `y`, `/` etc at second character. For example `0x`, `00`, `0Z`, `0#`... and so on